# List all files that start with an empty line

Tags: bash, grep

Struggling to find the answer to this...I've got a website with a bunch of PHP files, and somewhere there is an empty line before the opening php tag

So what I want to do is first try finding all files in a directory where the first line is an empty line.

Bonus points for a command that lets me search all files in a directory where there are one or more empty lines before the opening php tag..

```
<?php
```

Looking for a bash command that can do this...

Also, needs to recursively search all directories within that directory.

On Linux.....Thanks!

UPDATE:
Tried the suggestion from the John1024's answer, and this a file with the code below is being listed in the results

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Defines custom functionality for ...
 */
```

Comment: Well I have tried a lot of things, none of which worked, which is why I asked the question :)

Comment: On SO, it's better to show you tried something, then we can help complete it.  Bonus points :-)

Comment: @jackrabbithanna Nic3500 is right about proper form on StackOverflow.  If you add to your question some code that you tried, you will be less likely to get downvotes.

Comment: sorry, its the end of day frustration...Updating the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A perl oneliner

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print "$ARGV\n" if /^( *\n)+<\?php/' *
```

To recursively look in a directory:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -0777 -ne 'print "$ARGV\n" if /^( *\n)+<\?php/' {} +
```

for whoever ends up here:

```
-0777
```

[slurps](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) each file, make this task fairly trivial.

Comment: @jackrabbithanna you are welcome to accept the answer if it provided you with the solution.

Comment: Thanks @salparadise, with this I was able to solve the real problem, and my sanity lasts another day

Answer (score 1):

> "search all files in a directory where there are one or more empty lines before the opening php tag.."

To find all files in the current directory that have one or more blank lines before a line that contains `<?php`, try:

```
awk -v last=1 '/<?php/ && !last {print FILENAME; last=1; nextfile} {last=$0}' *
```

How it works:

- `-v last=1`

  Set the awk variable `last` to true (1).
- `/<?php/ && !last {print FILENAME; last=1; nextfile}`

  If the current line contains the string `<?php` and the last (previous) line was empty, then print the filename, reset `last` to true, and start on the next file.

#### Recursive search

```
find . -type f -exec awk -v last=1 '/<?php/ && !last {print FILENAME; last=1; nextfile} {last=$0}' {} +
```

Comment: ok, how about for recursively searching all directories too, within a directory?

Comment: @jackrabbithanna See updated answer for recursive search.

Comment: I think that updated command is giving me all files with a empty line after the php tag

Comment: well, its not giving me that exactly either, but I'm getting a bunch of false positives

Comment: Hmm.  That is not good.  Please take a very small file (if needed, cut unnecessary stuff out) that produces a false positive and paste it into your question as an update.

Comment: @jackrabbithanna I copied your file into my directory but I am unable to reproduce the false-positive problem.  Note that the assignment `last=1` occurs **twice** in the code.  Omitting either would lead to false positives.  So, make sure both are there.